# How to create/compile Custom Bash Runtime Lambda layers with /bin executables?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Did any one create bash custom layer for Lambda with executables ? Something like this (https://github.com/gkrizek/bash-lambda-layer). I tried to add some more executable's to bin which quite didnt workout. Is there a procedure on how to build & compile executables for bash ?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda executes on Amazon Linux.  Your executable must be compiled and linked on Amazon Linux.

See this project as an example : https://github.com/sebsto/swift-custom-runtime-lambda